# Twitter Bootstrap modal should create new instance every time it opens

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using `bootstrap-modal.js v2.3.2`

Whenever I close the model basically it toggles the modal, meaning previous data persists.

What I'd like is for:

- Every time I close or hide the modal, it should destroy its data.
- Every time I open the modal, it should create a new instance.

I tried something like :

```js
$('#update-addresstype').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('modal', null);
})
```

But it does not seems to be working.

Comment: You want to kill data in a form or what..?

Comment: yes / i am showing the select box in modal dilog box, when i hide and repoen the previous selected data still present there i need to show a fresh select box

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to "reset" a form, use jQuery `.reset()`, as below:

```
$('#update-addresstype').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('modal', null);
    $('form')[0].reset();
});
```

Or to reset a `<select />`, try this (be sure to change the `#select-id` and `value` to match your corresponding HTML):

```
$('#update-addresstype').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

    $('#select-id option').removeAttr('selected');
    $('#select-id option[value="0"]').attr('selected',true);

    $(this).data('modal', null);
});
```

Comment: If my first option didn't work, try my second option - see my edited answer.